# 通 character causes python to stop reading a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm reading a subtitle file (encoded in UCS-2) in python 2.7 with

```
f = 'filename.ssa'
with open(f, "r") as fl:
    allLines = fl.readlines()
```

and when it reaches this line

> Dialogue: 0,0:02:25.54,0:02:28.40,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,模木さん、手筈通り、火口にレシーバーを

It actually only reads in this, and then stops.

> Dialogue: 0,0:02:25.54,0:02:28.40,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,模木さん、手筈

If i remove the 通 character, it continues and reaches

> Dialogue: 0,0:05:41.28,0:05:42.77,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,{\fs30}計画通り…

but again, it only reads this and stops:

> Dialogue: 0,0:05:41.28,0:05:42.77,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,{\fs30}計画

Again, the 通 character stops the reading as if it is the end of the the file. no errors are thrown

It works if I first encode the file to UTF-8, but I don't want to do this. Can anyone explain why in UCS-2 this 通 character stops the reading? It also seems to work if i compile my python down to an exe with py2exe. i was developing in eclipse. this make no sense.

Comment: You'll need to show up *how* you are reading the file. What Python version are you using? Are you reading the file with `open()` or for Python 2, `codecs.open()` or `io.open()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"通" encoded in UCS-2 is 0x1a 0x90. 0x1a is also considered the EOF character ("^Z") in DOS files. Consider opening the file in binary mode via `codecs.open()`.

Comment: Consider `io.open()` instead; `codecs.open()` is not nearly as robust and featurefull.

Comment: I'm from the pre-`io` era. Maybe I should finally figure out how it works.

Comment: It's the Python 3 I/O framework; `__builtins__.open()` is `io.open()` in Python 3.